# Angular 7 use dom element on pure JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, webcam

Hi im using webcamJS library on my Angular project *(because i need to use webcam on IE 11)*, this library has a function called "attach" and it receive the ID of the element where the image is displayed, when i pass my div id it is not recognized in the library, if i check in the browser inspector, the div id is correct.

there is my html

```
<div  #my_camera ></div>   <!--div  id="my_camera" ></div -->
```

and my Ts which uses pure JS function

```
Webcam.attach("#my_camera");
```

i have tried without # but is the same.

the error on library is **"Could not locate DOM element to attach to."**

What is the best way to use JS in my TS? Why the JS is not recognizing the ID of my DIV?

Regards.

Comment: Can you show where you are using  `Webcam.attach("#my_camera")`. And why is your div with id "my_camera" commented?

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether your code works for other browsers or generates a similar error?  Check that you have hosted the site on a web server. Try to make a test with the HTTPS protocol. Make sure that Flash is enabled for the IE browser. Also, check that you are not using the above code in the model or dialog. It can cause [similar error](https://github.com/bcabanes/ng-camera/issues/15).

Comment: div with id is commented because i was trying to put id in 2 ways (**#** and **id=""**) but is the same error. im using attach method on ngAfterViewInit method.
`
ngAfterViewInit{
    Webcam.attach("#my_camera")
}
`

In other browsers is the same error i have tried on Fire Fox, Chrome and IE 11.

Comment: As per your previous comment, we can see that you are getting the same error in other browsers too. So based on that we can say that issue is specifically not related to the IE browser. There is some issue in your code that you may need to address to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<div  #my_camera ></div>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('my_camera') myCamaraView : ElementRef;
Webcam.attach(myCamaraView);
```

For more info check this : https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-elementref/

Comment: And do not forget to detach on ngDestroy !